# IP change after HTTP request

Tags: ip, httprequest, httpresponse

I want to change my IP address during making HTTP requests. I wonder if I change the IP what happens if any of the requests is not responded to yet. Will the response still be directed to the requester server even if the IP address of this server has changed?

Answer (score 1):

http is tcp based, this means that the question and reply go to the same socket (which is a point to point connection medium).  Now, if you change your ip address during a request (ie, there's traffic going through an established socket connection), on all operating systems I know of all open sockets will be closed (the link connecting you and the server will be cut).  Both the server and client will be notified of that event and will act accordingly, eg the client may decide to reopen the socket and repeat the request, and that request will originate on the new ip address.

The question remains what effect you actually want to achieve here, because this is a rather unusual sequence of events...